# Splitting Yeoman prompts into multiple separate groups

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

how would one split a yeoman prompt into parts?
I have a rather extended prompt that i'd like to split into parts with a title for each part.

```
CSS
- prompt1

HTML
-prompt 2
```

Something like this:

```
prompt1: function(){
  var done = this.async();
  condole.log('title 1');
  var prompts = [{
      name: 'prompt1',
      message: 'Prompt 1:',
    }]
},


prompt2: function(){
  var done = this.async();
  condole.log('title 2');
  var prompts = [{
      name: 'prompt2',
      message: 'Prompt 2:',
    }]
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** as @Deimyts notes in the comments, the original code stopped working. This is due to API changes in **Inquirer.JS** [documented here](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/releases/tag/v1.0.0).

> - The base API interface is now `inquirer.prompt(questions).then()`. There's no more callback function.
> - Any async question functions is taking a promise as return value instead of requiring `this.async()`.

In a nutshell, instead of using the old `var done = this.async()` API and resolving the prompt inside the callback with `done()` just return a promise from the `prompting` functions ([see docs](http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html)).

```js
prompt1: function() {
  this.log("HTML")
  return this.prompt([
      // configure prompts as before
    ]).then(function (answers) {
      // callback body as before, but no more calling done()
  }.bind(this));
},
```

***For more details see @Deimyts answer below.***

---

Yeoman uses a run loop with certain predefined priorities that you can use to put your actions into. As mentioned in the [☞ docs](http://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html) you can group several methods at one priority. Here is a snippet to illustrate a generator with prompts split into two groups `HTML` and `CSS`:

```js
'use strict';

var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = generators.Base.extend({

  constructor: function () {
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  prompting: {
    prompt1: function() {
      this.log("HTML")
      var done = this.async();
      this.prompt([{
          type    : 'input',
          name    : 'foo',
          message : 'Foo',
        }, {
          type    : 'input',
          name    : 'bar',
          message : 'Bar'
        }], function (answers) {
          this.foo = answers.foo;
          this.bar = answers.bar;
          done();
        }.bind(this));
    },

    prompt2: function() {
      this.log("CSS")
      var done = this.async();
      this.prompt([{
          type    : 'input',
          name    : 'bam',
          message : 'Bam',
        }], function (answers) {
          this.bam = answers.bam;
          done();
        }.bind(this));
    }
  },

  configuring: function () {
    console.log(this.foo, this.bar, this.bam);
  }
});
```

Using this feature of Yeoman you could modularize your code even further, e.g. by putting your different prompts in separate code files and `require` / `import` them into your generator file. But basically the above snippet should do the trick.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Great, glad to hear.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I'm using yeoman-generator v0.23.4. The generator asks only `prompt1`, and then quits. Removing `var done = this.async();` and `done();` lets it ask both questions, but then it doesn't wait for the answers.

Comment: Ok, I finally got the above example working, with a few modifications. My suspicion is that it's the result of using a different version of the `yeoman-generator` module, so I'm posting it as an answer below in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: @Deimyts seems like the signature for returning prompts has changed: http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html (it needs to return promises now) . I have updated it locally and it works again. Feel free to post your answer, otherwise I could edit mine to show an update.

Comment: @sthzg Yep, I think that's what I was missing, although I'm not 100% clear on the terminology. I've posted my answer. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer wasn't working for me until I made several modifications to the example code.

I can't be 100% certain, but I believe that the difference might be due to differing versions of the `yeoman-generator` module. So, I'm recording this here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

For reference, I'm using `yeoman-generator v0.23.4`, `yo v1.8.4`, `node v6.2.2`, & `npm v3.9.5`.

## Modifications:

1. Remove all instances of `var done = this.async();` and `done()`.

   The `async()` function was causing the generator to exit after `prompt1`, and never run `prompt2` or the `configuring` function.
2. Add `return` before calling `this.prompt()`;

   Removing `async()` causes the generator to rush through the prompts without waiting for an answer. Adding `return` fixes this.
3. Replace the callback function inside `this.prompt()` with `.then()`.

   Before making this change, the generator would run through the prompts correctly, but would not save the answers, and `configuring` would simply log `undefined undefined undefined`.

   **Original:** `this.prompt(prompts, callback(answers).bind(this))`

   **Revised**: `this.prompt(prompts).then(callback(answers).bind(this));`

## Full Example:

```
'use strict';

var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = generators.Base.extend({

  constructor: function () {
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  prompting: {
    prompt1: function() {
      this.log("HTML")
      return this.prompt([{
        type    : 'input',
        name    : 'foo',
        message : 'Foo',
      }, {
        type    : 'input',
        name    : 'bar',
        message : 'Bar'
      }]).then(function (answers) {
        this.foo = answers.foo;
        this.bar = answers.bar;
      }.bind(this));
    },

    prompt2: function() {
      this.log("CSS")
      return this.prompt([{
        type    : 'input',
        name    : 'bam',
        message : 'Bam',
      }])
      .then(function(answers) {
        this.bam = answers.bam;
      }.bind(this));
    }
  },

  configuring: function () {
    console.log(this.foo, this.bar, this.bam);  
    console.log('Config: ', this.config);
  },
});
```